# Android display parent and child data dynamically with Loop in ExpandableListview

Tags: android

I learning ExpandableListview now. So far I manage to display Parent and child data in hardcoding.

However, I need to get data from database and then display them dynamically.

Looks like this has to do with a For loop and then with a inner For loop. But I have been thinking the structure but failed. Anyone can help with this?

```
adapter adapter; // BaseExpandableListAdapter
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
List<String> category;
HashMap<String,List<String>> item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ex_listview);

    expandableListView=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    display();
    adapter=new adapter(this,category,item);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void display(){

    category=new ArrayList<String>();
    item=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    category.add("Western Food");
    category.add("Chinese Food");
    category.add("Japanese Food");

    List<String> western_food = new ArrayList<String>();
    western_food.add("Fried Chicken");
    western_food.add("French Fries");
    western_food.add("Beef Steak");

    List<String> chinese_food = new ArrayList<String>();
    chinese_food.add("Chicken Rice");
    chinese_food.add("Duck Rice");

    List<String> japanese_food = new ArrayList<String>();
    japanese_food.add("Tapanyaki");
    japanese_food.add("Takoyagi");
    japanese_food.add("Sushi");
    japanese_food.add("Lamian");

    item.put(category.get(0), western_food);
    item.put(category.get(1), chinese_food);
    item.put(category.get(2), japanese_food);

}
```

**screenshot of the result**

[image]

Imagine the database has 10 categories, each category with more than 10 items. Hardcoing obviously is not the right way to do that. Hence, I wish to display them with loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in JSON format which contains an array of Categories and each category has an array of items, which makes the sample data to look like

```
"categories": [
 {
   "name": "category1",
   "items": [
     "item1",
     "item2",
     "item3"
     ]
 },
 {
   "name": "category2",
   "items": [
     "item1",
     "item2",
     "item3",
     "item4"
     ]
 },
 {
   "name": "category3",
   "items": [
     "item1",
     "item2"
    ]
  }
]
```

You can parse the JSON data using for loop and in the same for loop you can add elements to expandable view as below

```
category=new ArrayList<String>();
item=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
JSONArray categoryList = new JSONArray(yourJsonData);
for(int i=0; i < categoryList.length(); i++){
    JSONObject category = categoryList.get(i);
    String categoryName = category.getString("name");

    JSONArray itemArray = category.getJSONArray("items");
    List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int j=0; j<itemArray.length(); j++){
        foods.add(itemArray.get(j));
    }
    item.put(categoryName,foods);
}
```

The above loop can replace your display() method for any size of data.

Comment: have u really tested the above method with Expandablelistview before?

Comment: Not exactly this code..But i have used expandable list with similar data as i have mentioned here.

Comment: what i want to achieve is what you have mentioned.  Php echo JSon data and then I parse the data into ExpandableListview.  I am thinking how to do that now